# sql query to get the completed group

Tags: sqlite

There is a table with site name:

```
 sites_tbl (name field):
 Site 001
 Site 002
 Site 005
```

I would like to get which of the sites are found in predefined list, then I used:

```
SELECT * FROM sites_tbl WHERE name IN ('Site 001', 'Site 006')
```

The answer will be 'Site 001'

But What If I would like to get the complement group, I mean to get all sites which are found in the list ('Site 001', 'Site 006') but not found in the table. In that case, I expected to get only the 'Site 006' as 'Site 001' is found in the table. ow can I query it?

Comment: So you are asking how to do NOT IN in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select something from `sites_tbl` if it isn't there.

SQL is about data in tables, not lists, so you need to get the data you want to return into a table, then make the query about that.
If the list you are checking against isn't already in a table, make a temporary table (using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl ...`), and use an antijoin (`NOT IN` in the where clause) to select the values not found in the `sites_tbl`.

```
select name from temp_tbl where name not in (select name from sites_tbl)
```

(To be clear, `temp_tbl` is arbitrary;it can be any name you want, unless the name is already in use. You will need to insert the values you want to check into `temp_tbl` before doing the select above.)